# c++ vector constructor with custom function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am currently working with a short snippet of code where I would like to take each value of one vector and call a wrapper class and put into a new vector.

```
vector<MyClass> input;
vector<WrapperClass> output;
output.reserve(input.size());
for (auto& myclass: input) {
    output.emplace_back(WrapperClass(myclass));
}
```

I know the above isn't terrible readability wise, but is something like the below possible:

```
vector<WrapperClass> output(input.begin(), input.end(), WrapperAllocator)
```

I'm not quite sure what an allocator is supposed to do and because of my unfamiliarity with "C++ concepts" a lot of the documentation goes right over my head. Maybe it is the wrong use case but the question really comes down to;

**Is it possible to transform the data as it's passed from one container to another?** And if possible how would it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to transform the data as it's passed from one container to another?

If your `WrapperClass` has constructor that takes `MyClass` you can create another vector from range directly and transform your data in that constructor, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass
{
    int x;
    MyClass(int x) : x{ x } {}
};

struct WrapperClass
{
    int x;
    WrapperClass(MyClass const &mc) 
    {
        x = mc.x + 10;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> v1 = { 1,2,3,4 };
    std::vector<WrapperClass> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end());


    //test
    for (auto wc : v2)
        std::cout << wc.x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/6MFd2s

```
11
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::transform( input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter( output ),
   []( const MyClass& c ){ return WrapperClass(c); } );
```

Comment: is back_inserter a type of allocator?

Comment: @Max No, it's a function which returns a type of iterator.  Each time the resulting iterator is used (within `transform` or otherwise) in an expression like `*iter++ = value`, it calls `output.push_back( value )`.